# Selected cell doesn't change value in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am sure almost that it's very easy but I can't find how...
I have `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and I need to update all cell values in this column like below:

```
private void HCStaffSelect_OnCheckBoxClicked(bool isChecked)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvStaffs.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            row.Cells[cStaffSelect.Index].Value = isChecked;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that focused (selected) cell doesn't change its value. How to change value so cells too?

Comment: maybe change or clear the selection `dgvStaffs.ClearSelection()`

Comment: @Slai I'll try. Thank u! I tried to commit edit but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataGridView.RefreshEdit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.refreshedit) can be used to refresh the value of the curenly editing cell:

```
for (int r = 0; r < dgvStaffs.RowCount - 1; r++)
     dgvStaffs[cStaffSelect.Index, r].Value = isChecked;

dgvStaffs.RefreshEdit();
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank u! But `dgvStaffs.RefreshEdit();` must be after the loop for correct behavior.